# Windows phone 8.1 ink manager alternative

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, inkmanager

I have an universal app and the windows version use ink manager to capture a signature. I want to do the same with the phone but the ink manager dont exist. Does anyone have or know an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a canvas named Display and add this code using two events.

```
  private Point _currentPoint;
    private Point _oldPoint;


    private async void Display_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawPoint(e);
    }

    private void DrawPoint(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        _currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position;

        Line linea = new Line
        {
             Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
             StrokeThickness=1,
             X1 = _currentPoint.X,
             Y1 = _currentPoint.Y,
             X2 = _oldPoint.X,
             Y2 = _oldPoint.Y
        };

        Display.Children.Add(linea);

        _oldPoint = _currentPoint;


    }

    private void Display_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        _currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position;
        _oldPoint = _currentPoint;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Input: XAML user input events sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-3dff271b/) in Microsoft MSDN code has a sample using pointer events with both C# and Visual Basic. Specifies Visual Studio 2013 but will probably upgrade with a later version of Visual Studio. And this example looks to be for Windows 8.1 however you might be able to use that as a starting place.

Comment: Thanks Luc, for my app and only used two events to create the lines to emulate a free drawing. I added the code as an answer for any other person in need.

Comment: Your welcome, code.microsoft.com is useful because is has working en basic examples, saved me several times